# grails spring-security-ui plugin redirect back to application

Tags: plugins, grails, spring-security

I am using the spring-security-ui plugin(0.1.2) and it is working very well for me. However, I am looking for the best way to get back to my application once a user is done making updates.

As it stands, if an Admin logs into my application and decides that a user needs to be added, they will be directed to the spring-security-ui plugin to perform this action. Once done, they may need to get back to the application to perform other Admin tasks. Is there a button/link that allows for this. If they choose to logout, they will be directed back to the app, but then they would have to log back in to perform the rest of their duties. Any advice on the best approach?

Thanks
-Juan

Answer (score 0):

Can't you redirect from, say, the **update** action in what I'm assuming is UserController.groovy? Currently, it would look something like

```
redirect action: edit, id: user.id
```

why not use something along the lines of

```
redirect controller: <your_controller>, action: <your_action>, ...
```

Comment: I suppose I could do that, but that would require me to generate the controller. As I remember when i wrote the question, the code was housed in the plugin. I was thinking that maybe there was a line I could add in the config.groovy file